# 3D CT baggage scanning images

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, d3dimage

I want to perform object recognition on the 3D CT luggage scan image. When training the neural network, which is better, the slice data of the input image or the whole volume image?

Has anyone done related work? can you give me some advice

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.